# authorization denied in a consent scenario in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have created a third-party app that i'd like to use in a consent scenario to provision some resources on behalf of the user in their subscription. 
The authentication code and the provisioning of a ResourceGroups are pasted below.
In the code below, `<some_client_id>` is the ClientID of the native app registered in AAD1. `<some_subscription_id>` is the subscription that the user (in AAD2) has access to.
I have verified user's access to the subscription by creating a ResourceGroup directly in the portal.
When I run the code I get prompted for login where I enter the credentials of the user (in AAD2). Then I get prompted to consent to the app being authorized. I have pasted what I see in the screen.
After that, the part that tries to create the resource throws an exception with the message:

"Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'"

This is the consent window contents:

```
JeffSaremiApp
App publisher website: jeffsaremiad.onmicrosoft.com 
JeffSaremiApp needs permission to:
• Access Azure Service Management as you (preview)  
• Read directory data  
• Access the directory as you  
• Read and write directory data  
• Sign you in and read your profile  
• Read directory data  
You're signed in as: jeff@jeffsaremihotmail.onmicrosoft.com
```

Here's the code that I used in this example:

```csharp
AuthenticationContext authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
AuthenticationResult result =
    authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net",
        <some_client_id>,
        new Uri("https://localhost"),
        new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)
    ).Result;
Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
ResourceGroup rg = NewResourceGroupAync(result.AccessToken,
    "mytestrg",
    <some_subscription_id>,
    "East US",
    null,
    true).Result;
Console.WriteLine(rg.Name);

public static async Task<ResourceGroup> NewResourceGroupAync(string accessToken,
    string name,
    string subscriptionId,
    string location,
    IDictionary<string, string> tags,
    bool overwrite)
{
    using (var client = new ResourceManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(accessToken)) { SubscriptionId = subscriptionId })
    {
        if (overwrite && client.ResourceGroups.CheckExistence(name) == true)
        await client.ResourceGroups.DeleteAsync(name);
        var result = client.ResourceGroups.CreateOrUpdateAsync(name,
        new ResourceGroup { Location = location, Tags = tags });
        return await result;
    }
}
```

Comment: The last error (requiredResourceAccess list) was due to the incorrect URL. I changed it from https://manage.windowsazure.com to https://management.core.windows.net and it went away
However I still get the Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized' when I try to create a resource group

Comment: I must also mention that if I login to azure interactively i am able to create the same resource group in the same location

Comment: What do you mean by "login to azure interactively"? You mean to the Azure portal, or with Azure PowerShell?

Comment: What permissions have you configured on the application?

Comment: by interactive i meant login into portal.azure.com. I don't think i would have any problems with powershell either

Comment: I wish i could attach a picture here but on the Applications>Configure page of AAD where I registered my native app I added the following:
1. Windows Azure Service Management API - 1 delegated perm: Access Azure Management ...
2. Microsoft Graph - 2 delegated perms: "Access Directory as Signed in" and "Read and write directory data"
3. Windows Azure Active Directory: 2 delegated perms: "sign in and read user profile" and "read directory data"

Comment: Can you update your question with the corrected code you're using to get the access tokens, the request you're making to attempt to create a resource group, and the specific error message you're getting in response?

Comment: I revised the whole post. please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Scenario**

- `UserA` is originally in `AAD1`, and is also an external user in `AAD2`.
- The Azure subscription `AzureSub1` is associated with `AAD2`.
- There is a native client app `App` (registered in `AAD1`, though that's irrelevant for a native client app) requesting access to the Azure Management API (`AzureAPI`).
- `UserA` can sign in to the app, and is prompted for consent, but when the app attempts to perform an action in `AzureSub1`, the response is `Unauthorized`.

**What's happening**

Let's walk through the token acquisition and API request to see what's happening:

1. `App` send the user to sign in to the "common" Azure AD endpoint (as opposed to the directory-specific authority): `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`.
2. `UserA` signs in, and as a result, `App` receives an access token to `AzureAPI`, on behalf of `UserA` *in directory `AAD1`*. (This is the critical point: when using the "common" endpoint, access tokens retrieved will always be for a user's "home" directory.)
3. `App` attempts to use the access token to perform an action on `AzureAPI`, for `AzureSub1` (which, remember, is associated with `AAD2`).
4. `AzureAPI` receives the request, and fails the authorization immediately because the access token is for a user in `AAD1`, yet the request is for a subscription in `AAD2`.

**Solution**

To get around this, you need to authenticate the user using the directory-specific endpoint for `AAD2` (which is where `AzureSub1` is): `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}`, where `{tenant-id}` is either the Guid directory identifier, or any verified domain name (including the initial `{something}.onmicrosoft.com` domain name).

Using the common endpoint says "sign user user in to whatever their home directory is". Using the directory-specific endpoint says "sign the user into *this* directory (and fail if they aren't a member).

**Going further**

Hard-coding your app to use a directory-specific endpoint may not be ideal, especially if you're building an app that will be used by other users in other directories. Fortunately, there is a process to discover which other directories a user is a member of, and allow them to switch (the same process which is used in the [new Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com), where a user can change which directory they're signed in to).

1. First, use the "common" endpoint to authenticate the user (to their home directory).
2. Offer the user the ability to switch directories.
3. If a different directory is chosen, re-authenticate the user on the directory-specific endpoint as the authority (i.e. do the access token dance again).

To offer the user the ability to switch directories, you would make use of the [`List all tenants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790536.aspx) API method to discover the `tenantId` of all the directories the user is a member of.

In the Azure SDK for .NET, this is achieved with [SubscriptionClient.Tenants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.subscriptions.subscriptionclient.tenants.aspx) property:

```csharp
var clientId = "{client-id}";
var replyUrl = "{reply-uri}";

// Get an access token to Azure Management API using the common endpoint
AuthenticationContext authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
AuthenticationResult result =
    authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
        "https://management.core.windows.net/",
        clientId,
        new Uri(replyUrl),
        new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always)
    ).Result;

// List the authority endpoints for all tenants the user a is a member of
using (var client = new SubscriptionClient(new TokenCredentials(result.AccessToken)))
{
    var tenants = client.Tenants.List();
    foreach (var tenant in tenants)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenant.TenantId);
    }
}
```

Since the user is already authenticated in their home directory, there's no need to force prompt (or, in fact, to prompt at all). You can use ADAL's `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` to use the cached credentials to re-authenticate the user against the new authority:

```csharp
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var result = authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resource, clientId).Result;
var accessToken = result.AccessToken
```

Comment: I will try what you listed here. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Comment: This statement is not in my scenario:
UserA is originally in AAD1, and is also an external user in AAD2.
The user (any user in this scenario) belongs only to AAD2. The App is registered in AAD1 as native or multi-tenant app.

Comment: Philippe, i cannot thank you enough! your suggestions worked flawlessly. thanks again

Comment: I have a question on the last segment:
When the second AuthenticationContext is created it looks like it has nothing to do with the first one (the one created for "common"). What prevents the library from failing the second call (AcquireTokenSilentAsync)? How does it know that we already went through the first call (AcquireTokenAsync)?
thanks

Comment: ADAL has a token cache that is used whenever possible. `AcquireTokenSilent` will attempt to use the cache (or fail outright if it can't). The cache may provide the access token directly, or it may provide a token that can be exchanged for a new one. Here, the cache is providing a refresh token (obtained in the first `AcquireTokenAsync`), which is exchanged for a new access token/refresh token pair from the new authority. The default token cache implementation is a static instance: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/guidance-multitenant-identity-token-cache/